# What is the difference between a differential aka ( Total differential ) and a derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This question is NOT a similar question on Mathematics Stack Exchange that asks " What is a differential?.  I am asking what is the difference between a derivative and a differential.  AND please read the rest of the question before you begin typing an answer. Thank you. By they way I assume Total differential and differential are the same thing, or at least the professor appears to me to be using them to be the same thing. And lets confine ourselves only with x,y,z.

In a nutshell I think a differential is taking the derivative of one variable while holding the other variables constant temporarily, just like you do when you take a partial derivative, until you can finish using the chain rule on dx, dy, dz and if there is yet another variable say t that x , y and z rely on then differentiate with respect to t with the chain rule ; otherwise leave it at dx , dy , dz.

I see NO new animal but the instructor says the differential is not a number, not a matrix , not a vector but a new animal...., but it seems to me to be a number like the derivative and just a derivative accept in 3 dimensions and with a potentially extra variable that x, y and z rely on while x , y and z are also changing.  I don't get what he is saying.

Comment: I don't quite get the last part on the variable "t", could you explain what you mean?

Comment: yes....lets say for example  w= x^3yz + xy + z  and x = 3cost,  y = 3 sint, and z = 2t now compute dw/dt at t = pi/2 . This is just an example you don't need to do it! but here you have your variables x,y z but they depend on t.   The question can still be answered if you just restrict yourself to x, y , z that will be enough for me to understand,  I was just trying to be complete.

Comment: isn't it just a number?  and isn't is related to the derivative with dy = f'(x) dx ? so why is the total differential any different than the differential as seen in 2 d calculus...it's seems all the same to me but yet the professor is making a big stink that the differential is a NEW animal.  I must be missing the point. You use the partial derivative to get the total differential and they you apply the chain rule if you need it ..then you get a freaking number so what's the big stink with the prof.?

Comment: In your example, let $w = f(x,y,z) = x^3yz+xy+z$ and $r(t) = (x(t),y(t),z(t))$. So $f\circ r$ is a function $\Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$. So that you could just use chain rule as in 1D case or even simply plug those $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ in to compute $dw$.

Comment: Yet I would agree your prof that multivariable differentiation is a different animal. Their definitions are different. In multivariable case ($\Bbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^m$), the total derivative at a point must be formulated in terms of linear transformation, as opposed to derivative in 1D case, the derivative at a point is just a number.

Comment: If your course didn't teach that definition yet, we can look at linear approxiamation for the function $f:\Bbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$. $f(\vec x+\vec h) \approx f(\vec x)+\nabla f(\vec x) \cdot h =f(\vec x) + h_1\partial_xf(\vec x) + h_2\partial_yf(\vec x) + h_3 \partial_zf(\vec x)$, so that derivative in higher dimensions is more than just one number, in this case we have 3. (we can write this as $df = \partial_xf dx +\partial_yf dy+\partial_zf dz $)

Comment: ahhh....I am beginning to see the light so are you saying the total differential is in fact a transformation?

Comment: Yes. It’s a linear map associated with a point in the domain of $f$ that takes as input a displacement from that point and outputs an approximation to the change $f$’s value.